# Pandas find values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that i would like to combine. The first one is ~3000 rows long  has 3 columns: source and a target and a volume containing multiple source and target combinations:

| Source | Target | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| source 1 | target 1 | 3 |
| source 2 | target 2 | 1 |

E

From this i have separated two data frames for source and targets with corresponding volumes. After that i created another data frame to house the data in these two data frames under single column called parts. I also calculated some values (count, min, mean, max) based on the frequency of each part and their volumes in the original data frame

| part | count | min | mean | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| target 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 10 |

i would like to combine these two so that the right values are taken from the second data frame based on the source and target and then combined. I would like to have the initial data frame as follows:

| Source | Source count | S. min | S. mean | S. max | Target | Target count | T. min | T. mean | T. max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | target 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 10 |

I am probably doing this more complicated than i should when i am separating the sources and targets etc.
Is there a simple way to combine these data frames the way i want? Basically a to search the second data frame part column for both source and target and add correct values to the original one.

DIT: The original data frame can have same values in both source and target columns and this should be taken in consideration:

| Source | Target | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 |
| B | C | 1 |
| C | A | 3 |
| B | A | 1 |

outcome would be:

| Source | Source count | S. min | S. mean | S. max | Target | Target count | T. min | T. mean | T. max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 1 | 2.33 | 3 | B | 3 | 1 | 1.66 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 1 | 1.66 | 3 | C | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| C | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | A | 3 | 1 | 2.33 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 1 | 1.66 | 3 | A | 3 | 1 | 2.33 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df
    Source  Target  volume
0   A       B       3
1   B       C       1
2   C       A       3
3   B       A       1
```

As all the calculations has to be done independent of `Source`, `Target`. So, for calculations, it is better to take it as a same column. So, concatenating vertically `Source-Volume` table and `Target-Volume` table

```
temp_df = pd.concat([df[['Source', 'volume']].rename(columns={'Source': 'Source_Target'}),
                     df[['Target', 'volume']].rename(columns={'Target': 'Source_Target'})], ignore_index=True)
temp_df
  Source_Target volume
0      A            3
1      B            1
2      C            3
3      B            1
4      B            3
5      C            1
6      A            3
7      A            1
```

Now, you can get all the calulations using `groupby` and `agg`

```
temp_df = temp_df.groupby('Source_Target')['volume'].agg(
    count = 'count',
    min = 'min',
    mean = 'mean',
    max = 'max'
)
temp_df
```

[image]

Finally, merge `df` with the `temp_df` based on `Source` and then based on `Target`.

```
(df
 .drop('volume', axis=1)
 .merge(temp_df, left_on='Source', right_on='Source_Target', how='left') # 'left' to retain order
 .reindex(['Source', 'count', 'min', 'mean', 'max', 'Target'], axis=1)
 .rename(columns={'count': 'Source count', 'min': 'S .min', 'max': 'S .max', 'mean': 'S .mean'})
 .merge(temp_df,  left_on='Target', right_on='Source_Target', how='left')
 .rename(columns={'count': 'Target count', 'min': 'T .min', 'max': 'T .max', 'mean': 'T .mean'}))
```

[image]

Comment: This actually solves the problem I stated but I forgot to mention that source and targets can have same values e.g. source 1 can be the same as target 7 for instance. How could I do this but take it in consideration also? Your solution would assume that source and target can never be the same right? My bad as I forgot to mention this. Could I first somehow combine sources and targets from the original df into a single column and then calculate the other values and after that combine the way you showed here?

Comment: As for now there is over 3000 rows of source and target combinations but only 150 or so unique source and target names.

Comment: With what you have mentioned, I think it still works. Can you give an example where you think it would fail?

Comment: target_df = df.groupby('Target')['volume'].agg(
    count = 'count',
    min = 'min',
    mean = 'mean',
    max = 'max'
)

Comment: It only takes the values based on the target column. As there can be same target and source so in that case the count does not calculate the ones in the source column and that makes the averages etc. to be incorrect.

Comment: What im after is to calculate count, min, max and mean to all different target and source names that can be same in both groups and then add them back for each source and target pairs like you showed here alread

Comment: I got slightly but am getting confused. But if you  can give the example of original input df and final df, it would be clear. I think you have not given the original inpurt df

Comment: I edited the original question if it makes the problem more clear. What im after is that  both columns can have same values. But for now the count etc. only counts the ones in the Target and Source columns separately. Lets say we have a part that is named "screw" and it is both columns, 3 times in "source" and 4 times in "target". Now it only counted per column and not for total instances of 7. the value in the final df now depends of which column it is.

Comment: got the problem. Can you also give the expected output for the new df?

Comment: the expexted output is the same but the the values should be counted for total frequency in both column e.g. it should be the same no matter which column the part is originally from.

Comment: what i mean is if there should be only one count, mean, min and max value per part. not two separate ones for part "A" in source and part "A" in target as for now they can differ based on column?

Comment: it is a small table. you can give the expected output.  Otherwise, it is confusing like what would be the count of A as source, what would be  count of A as target.

Comment: I edited the original post again to show what should the outcome be. As you can see i want all A B and C to have same values no matter which they are, source or a target

Comment: Ideal solutiuon would probably be to list all parts with corresponding count, min,mean and max values in a different df and search values from there based on the part name in each column

Comment: Yes thanks, now it seems to work like i expected. Thank you and sorry for my bad explanation of the problem!